# How to solve this product?

Tags: summation, proof-explanation, infinite-product

I was reading the [Wolfram article on infinite products](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InfiniteProduct.html) again, and the product 
$$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1 + \frac{1}{n^k})$$
Is solved on there. I was wondering if anyone knows how to do that? I tried checking the source but couldn't actually find it.

Comment: The source is given as "D. W. Cantrell, pers. comm., Mar. 29, 2006", so the results are quoted from personal communication ...

Comment: So we can't access the proof?

Comment: ... but if you get a hand on "Prudnikov et al. 1986, p. 754" for (27), the result (28) follows readily as $(1+1/n^k)=(1-1/n^{2k})/(1-n^k)$. Prudnikov, A. P.; Brychkov, Yu. A.; and Marichev, O. I. "Infinite Products." §6.2 in [Integrals and Series, Vol. 1: Elementary Functions](http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/2881247369/ref=nosim/ericstreasuretro). New York: Gordon & Breach, pp. 753-757, 1986.

Comment: I thought the same thing. I can't find any of his books /:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $Z = \{ \omega \in \mathbb{C} : \omega^k = -1\}$. Then

$$ 1 + \frac{1}{n^k} = \prod_{\omega \in Z} \left(1 - \frac{\omega}{n} \right). $$

Now plugging this back, the partial product is

$$ \prod_{n=1}^{N} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n^k} \right)
= \prod_{\omega \in Z} \prod_{n=1}^{N} \left(1 - \frac{\omega}{n} \right)
= \prod_{\omega \in Z}  \frac{\Gamma(N+1-\omega)}{\Gamma(1-\omega)N!}. $$

In view of the Stirling's approximation, we know that

$$ \frac{\Gamma(N+1-\omega)}{N!} \sim \frac{1}{N^{\omega}} \quad \text{as} \quad N \to \infty, $$

and since $\sum_{\omega \in Z} \omega = 0$ for $k \geq 2$, we obtain

$$ \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n^k} \right)
= \prod_{\omega \in Z}  \frac{1}{\Gamma(1-\omega)}. \tag{*} $$

When $k$ is even, then we know that $\omega \in Z$ if and only if $-\omega \in Z$, and in this case, we can group the factor according to this parity and then utilize the Euler's reflection formula to write

$$ \frac{1}{\Gamma(1-\omega)\Gamma(1+\omega)} = \frac{1}{\omega \Gamma(1-\omega)\Gamma(\omega)} = \frac{\sin(\pi \omega)}{\pi \omega}. $$

You may plug this back to simplify the product $\text{(*)}$.

Comment: How did you get the first line, exactly?

Comment: @RyanGoulden, This is a factorization. If a polynomial $p(x) = x^k + a_{1}x^{k-1} + \cdots + a_k \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ has zeros $x_1, \cdots, x_k \in \mathbb{C}$, then $p(x) = \prod_{j=1}^{k} (x - x_j)$. Dividing both sides by $x^k$, we get $$ 1 + \sum_{j=1}^{k} \frac{a_{j}}{x^j} = \prod_{j=1}^{k} \left(1 - \frac{x_j}{x} \right). $$ In our case, $p(x) = x^k + 1$ and $\{x_1, \cdots, x_k\} = Z$.

Comment: ...I read too fast. I didn't pay too much attention to the set $Z$. Clearly that set has $k$ elements. I think I see it now. But how exactly is that the entire proof?

Comment: @RyanGoulden, I admit that this is only a sketch of proof, but the answer presented in MathWorld is more or less the formula $\text{(*)}$ with some brushing-up. For instance, when $k$ is odd, then $\Gamma(1-\omega) = (-\omega)\Gamma(-\omega)$ and using the equality $\prod_{\omega\in Z} (-\omega) = (-1)^{k+1} = 1$, we obtain $$\text{$k$ odd :}\qquad\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n^k}\right)=\prod_{j=1}^{k}\frac{1}{\Gamma(-e^{i(2j-1)\pi/k})}.$$ This can be simplified further to yield the formula as in MathWorld.

Comment: For $\sum_{ \w \in \Z} \w^{k}$, may we write it as $\sum_{n=1}^{m} (-1)^{-\frac{k}{n}$?